# Slow Windows Server performance after starting windows service.

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-server-2008

I am using Windows Services built in C-sharp code which processes txt files and loads its content to oracle 11g database.
I have installed it in windows server 2008. I am facing issue of slow server performance after I Start that service. Each time I am starting service, server performance gets slow. what can be the actual cause... Please help as I am in last stage of service deployment in clients server. I dont want my WinService to harm any clients server. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) on the server and inspect the Windows Services in order to determine what slows the server down.